# MySQL huge tables, performance improvement with migration to NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, relational-database, nosql

We have few very big tables  (3 tables, each 2 ~ 5 GB) in our MySQL DB. We are running logistic applications where we combine entities like route,schedule,capacity,location,price rules etc.. and those huge tables contains "joined" data from mentioned entities.

We must have those tables because doing JOINS on-the-run kills performance totally. We do have indexes ;), caching mechanisms,efficient prepared statements,proper transaction management setup but performance is not sufficient (~ thousands of customers, ~hundreds or VIP customers).

Our customers are doing mostly **99% read-only** operations like searching for connections,schedule,pricing, and then sometimes there is some **1-2% of UPDATE/INSERT operations e.g. booking some** journey,capacity etc....

Our idea is to use some no-sql DB (propably MongoDB) as second database where we would put all *pregenerated* read-only data into some key-value or tree structures. We believe that performance will be much better, what are the caveeats of this solution ? Do you have personal experience with such task ?

*We plan to make fast prototype but nobody has actually real experience with NoSQL.*

Comment: How many _rows_ do you have; it could be the size of your db is large because you are storing large amounts of data; but the rows make the difference. Have you already run [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on the consolidated table to see your query preformance? For read-only tables it is better to add indices (even combined indicies) to speed up queries. Large number of indices on read/write tables slow down write performance, but on read-only tables they offer a good performance benefit. Once you have this in place, then its easier to evaluate other solutions.

Comment: number of rows is around 8 ~ 19 milion in those huge tables. We identified around TOP 20 queries which causes most pain, we optimized some of them.

Comment: Have you eliminated the hardware as your bottleneck?

Comment: For the record, 2-5G is a pretty small table these days.  When you're getting close to a terabyte in a single table, then it's "big"

Comment: We run in cloud but before we raise money for bigger/better DB storage we want to investigate other ways for optimalization. And we are keen to try new technologies, that`s why we are considering No SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a lot of JOINed data in your data model, then MongoDB is definitely **not** the right choice, because it doesn't support joins. You aren't saying much about your data model, but when you can convert it in a way where most data is embedded in other entities and not stored in separate collections, then MongoDB could work for you. Thanks to sharding and replica sets it scales very well, especially for write access.

Or did you consider caching your three huge tables with Memcached? 3 x 5 GB = 15 GB - that's not much for a server to keep in memory.

Answer (score 2):

All your guys should familiar the memcache's k-v structure, right?
Standing on your team, NoSQL could be thought as a memcache with storages.
You could restructure datas into a NoSQL as using a memcache.

Then you will find all things becomes easy.

In a words, ignore the advanced feature, take the first step.